# Back to basics: Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

New to scrapy and I definitely need pointers. I've run through some examples and I'm not getting some basics. I'm running scrapy 1.0.3

Spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from matrix_scrape.items import MatrixScrapeItem


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "matrix"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2061039712/matrix-the-internet-of-things-for-everyonetm"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2061039712/matrix-the-internet-of-things-for-everyonetm"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = MatrixScrapeItem()
        item['backers'] = hxs.select("//*[@id="backers_count"]/data").extract()
        item['totalPledged'] = hxs.select("//*[@id="pledged"]/data").extract()
        print backers, totalPledged
```

item:

```
import scrapy


class MatrixScrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()

    backers = scrapy.Field()
    totalPledged = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

I'm getting the error:

```
File "/home/will/Desktop/repos/scrapy/matrix_scrape/matrix_scrape/spiders/test.py", line 15
    item['backers'] = hxs.select("//*[@id="backers_count"]/data").extract()
```

Myquestions are: Why isn't the selecting and extracting working properly? I do see people just using Selector a lot instead of HtmlXPathSelector.

Also I'm trying to save this to a csv file and automate it based on time (extract these data points every 30 min). If anyone has any pointers for examples of that, they'd get super brownie points :)

Comment: If you are on Linux you can set up a cron script to run every 30 min with this line "0,30 * * * * python your_script.py"

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is caused by the way you use double quotes. Mix single and double quotes:

```
item['backers'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="backers_count"]/data').extract()
item['totalPledged'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="pledged"]/data').extract()
```

As a side note, you can use [`response.xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.xpath) shortcut instead of instantiating `HtmlXPathSelector`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = MatrixScrapeItem()
    item['backers'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="backers_count"]/data').extract()
    item['totalPledged'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="pledged"]/data').extract()
    print backers, totalPledged
```

And you've probably meant to get the `text()` of the `data` elements:

```
//*[@id="backers_count"]/data/text()
//*[@id="pledged"]/data/text()
```